# Workaround for being unable to use initializer lists with unique_ptr?

Tags: c++

I'd like to have an array of polymorphic types that is generated at compile-time. Access into the array is dictated at runtime (otherwise I would just use a tuple). I would like the array to own its elements through a unique_ptr. Currently I'm using variadic templates to create the array. A simplified version of what I'm trying to do (MSVC 2012 November CTP):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foo { };
class bar : public foo { };
class wiz : public foo { };

struct house
{
    template<class... args>
    struct furniture
    {
        typedef tuple<args...> t;

        static std::array<unique_ptr<foo>, tuple_size<t>::value> make()
        {
            std::array<unique_ptr<foo>, tuple_size<t>::value> l = { unique_ptr<args>(new args())... }; 
            return l;
        }
    };

    typedef furniture<bar, wiz> td;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto result = house::td::make();

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm greeted with the compiler error:

```
error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>'
```

This is because initializer lists work through copies, but unique_ptr is not copyable. I can work around this by using shared_ptr (or raw pointers), which provides the behavior I want, but I'm curious if there's a way to create an array of unique_ptr like this. I'm still trying to wrap my head around variadic templates.

Comment: Works for me, on the same compiler. I think the problem is that you are trying to copy the array and return the copy.

Comment: VS2012 has initializer_list implemented?

Comment: @billz Yes but the standard library hasn't been updated so they don't really work as they should. Arrays already supported construction from initializer lists so that is why it works in this case. [Link to the November compiler new features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Does the RHS need to initialize with `unique_ptr`s? Cant the `unique_ptr`s constructor be used? Have you tried just

```
std::array<unique_ptr<foo>, tuple_size<t>::value> l = { new args()... };
```

Comment: The unique_ptr constructor is marked explicit so this doesn't work :(. A good thought though.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do essentially works:

```
std::array<unique_ptr<foo>, tuple_size<t>::value> l = { unique_ptr<args>(new args())... };
```

will compile (even on MSVC!) as you are constructing from temporaries and the move constructor will be called (and if it wasn't, adding `std::move` would have fixed it).

What you are trying to do next doesn't:

```
return l;
```

because you are trying to return the array of un-copyable unique_ptrs by value.

Comment: I see now. How can I return the array then? Using move and forward on the return does not seem to help.

Comment: Make it static and return by reference.